# 404 a page not found in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting a 404 page not found when trying to use the 'users/{id}' route, the route 
leads to the ProfilesController@edit method

**Profiles Controller:**

```
public function edit($id){
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        return view('profiles.edit', compact('user'));
    }
```

here is the routes in my web.php;

```
Route::get('/users/{id}', 'ProfilesController@edit')->name('user.edit');
Route::put('/users/{id}/update', 'ProfilesController@update')->name('user.update');
```

and i have a edit.blade file in my profiles folder

Comment: trying to use `'profite/{id}'` .. your routes are for `'users/{id}'` not `'profite/{id}'`

Comment: i'm using the users/{id} to get the ProfilesController

Comment: so why does your question say "I'm getting a 404 page not found when trying to use the 'profite/{id}' route"

Comment: did you try to clear your view caches (php artisan view:clear) and route caches (php artisan route:clear) ??

Comment: Is user exists? Try to `dd($user)` in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Change route to this, the call users/{id} instead of profile/{id}. Otherwise you can stick with your approach by using the second option below.

```
Route::get('/users/{id}/edit', 'ProfilesController@edit')->name('user.edit');
Route::put('/users/{id}', 'ProfilesController@update')->name('user.update');
```

Also you are trying to access the route `profile/{id}` but which for my undestanding it is not defined. You either will have to change your route to:

```
Route::get('/profile/{id}', 'ProfilesController@edit')->name('user.edit');
Route::put('/profile/{id}/update', 'ProfilesController@update')->name('user.update');
```

Comment: Why this should solve the issue, explain your answer.

Comment: please explain your answer i'm using the route(/user/{id)/edit) please explain to me the route to fetch the view(profiles.view)

Comment: @livreson i'm now getting this error **Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Route [profile.update] not defined. (View: C:\Users\user pc\Desktop\dkn\resources\views\profiles\edit.blade.php)** please any clue on what to do

Comment: It is probably because of route naming If you look at the code above, we named the update route as user.update not profile.update. Please rename it to `->name('profile.update');` which will look like  `Route::put('/profile/{id}/update', 'ProfilesController@update')->name('profile.update');`